# Gremlin date filter approach

Tags: gremlin, titan

Is there anyway to query on date in titan/gremlin?
e.g. find all results in the last X days

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach is to simply store the date as a Long value and to possibly index upon such a field in an edge such that you could take advantage of `limit()`, `interval`, etc.  See this Titan wiki page on the topic:

https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Vertex-Centric-Indices

It maps to your specific request with a Twitter example where it indexes on `time`.  You could find results based on `time` by simply calculating milliseconds for "X days" back and then finding all results that come after that:

```
g.v(1).outE.has('time',T.gte, fiveDaysAgoInMs).inV
```

Note that as of Titan 0.4.1 you can also define the directionality of the index such that newest items are returned first (no need to reverse index the property anymore):

https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Type-Definition-Overview#sortkeytitantype-and-signaturetitantype

Also, if you don't mind a little denormalization you could also store the date as a sortable String value ([iso-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for example) in addition to the Long value.  That helps you easily see what a date is without extra conversion.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I will try and let you know how it goes.