# Titan: Range query in graph

Tags: graph-databases, titan

I am using `Titan Graph Database`. Say if i have a vertex `V` with id `VID` and there 10K vertices attached to it v1 with id v1id, v2 with id v2id...................v10000 with id v10000id.

Now i want pagination in getting neighbour vertices i.e 10 vertex detail per call.

It should support `next` and `previous` result. I saw `limit()` but it just limit the number of returned result. I saw [**THIS SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20567483/gremlin-date-filter-approach) and seems close to what i need, but is there some range kind of thing in `Titan` where i can pass the start vertex id and the number of result i want??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Gremlin you can pass indices for ranges:

```
  // for the second ten links
  g.v(1).outE.has('time',T.gte, fiveDaysAgoInMs)[10..19]

  // for the previous ten links
  g.v(1).outE.has('time',T.gte, fiveDaysAgoInMs)[0..9]

  // for the next ten links
  g.v(1).outE.has('time',T.gte, fiveDaysAgoInMs)[20..29]

  // for one link only
  g.v(1).outE.has('time',T.gte, fiveDaysAgoInMs)[0..<1]
```

Source: [GremlinDocs](http://gremlindocs.com/#recipes/paging-results)

In Java code:

```
Graph g = ... // a reference to a Blueprints graph
GremlinePipeline pipe = new GremlinPipeline();

Long DAY_IN_MS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

// first 10
pipe.start(g.getVertex(1)).outE().has("time", Tokens.gte, new Date(date.getTime() - (5 * DAY_IN_MS))).range(0, 10));

// if you want next 10
pipe.next(10);
```

Source: [GremlinPipeline](http://www.tinkerpop.com/maven2/com/tinkerpop/gremlin/gremlin-java/1.5/api/com/tinkerpop/gremlin/java/GremlinPipeline.html), [Using Gremlin though Java](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Using-Gremlin-through-Java)

Comment: what is `DAY_IN_MS` ?whts is its value